# Java Lambda style

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

So, this doesn't work, since seatsAvailable is final. How can what I'm trying to accomplish be done using more of a lambda-style-from-the-ground-up way?

```
final boolean seatsAvailable = false;
theatreSeats.forEach(seat -> {
    if (!seatsAvailable) seatsAvailable = seat.isEmpty();
});
```

Comment: You could always just use a for loop. Streams don't really get you anything here.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It looks like you want `seatsAvailable` to be `true` if there is at least one empty seat.  Therefore, this should do the trick for you:

```
final boolean seatsAvailable = theatreSeats.stream().anyMatch(Seat::isEmpty);
```

(Note: I am assuming that your class is named `Seat`.)